# geonames-dump to sqlite python error 'dict_items' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, database, sqlite, python-3.x, geonames

I'm getting this error when running the python code from below

```
'dict_items' object does not support indexing
```

https://github.com/commodo/geonames-dump-to-sqlite/blob/master/geonames_dump_to_sqlite.py

what the code does is get files from geonames and put the results in a sqlite database.

it runs fine until creating the tables

```
def create_tables(cur):
    '''
    Create empty tables which will be populated later.
    '''
    for table_name in TABLE_MAPPINGS.values():
        cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s' % table_name)
        table_fields = [ "%s %s" % table_field.listitems()[0] for table_field in TABLE_FIELDS ]
        cur.execute('CREATE TABLE %s (%s)' % (table_name, ','.join(table_fields)))
```

error specifics:

```
  line 111, in <listcomp>
    table_fields = [ "%s %s" % table_field.items()[0] for table_field in TABLE_FIELDS ]
TypeError: 'dict_items' object does not support indexing
```

Comment: `table_field.items()[0]` is a `dict.items()` dictionary view. How did you create `TABLE_FIELDS`?

Comment: Your code and traceback do not match; you inserted the word `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3, `dict.items()` returns a dictionary view, not a list object. You can convert it to a list here (there is only one key and value per `TABLE_FIELDs` entry anyway):

```
table_fields = [ "%s %s" % list(table_field.items())[0] for table_field in TABLE_FIELDS ]
```

Later on, you'll run into the same problem, because the code tries to do the same to `table_field.keys()`:

```
table_fields = [ "%s" % list(table_field.keys()[0] for table_field in TABLE_FIELDS ]
```

Change that to:

```
table_fields = [ "%s" % list(table_field)[0] for table_field in TABLE_FIELDS ]
```

Both uses could also be replaced with `next(iter(table_field.items()))` and `next(iter(table_field))`, respectively.

I have no idea why the author used a list of one-key dictionaries there; it'd have been easier if the code used tuples instead:

```
TABLE_FIELDS = [('parentid',        'integer'),
                ('geonameid',       'integer'),
                ('name',            'text'),
                # etc.
```

then use `% table_field` and `% table_field[0]` respectively.

There may be other Python 3 incompatibilities in that script, however.

Comment: thx for the quick reply.now i get TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation... sry never worked with python.

Comment: @user3217115: you cannot mix tabs and spaces. Use spaces for indentation *only* if at all possible. Run the script with `python -tt scriptname.py` to have Python tell you where you have broken the indentation by mixing tabs and spaces.